# How to merge multiple streams inside a stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I'm trying to use the tab bar and tab bar view to appear some elements of the fire base. First, I used stream builder to get the text of the tabs in the tab bar:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
final FirebaseUser user;


  HomePage({this.user});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection("places").snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
        if (!snapshot.hasData){
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
      else{
      return DefaultTabController(
      length: 20,
      child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text("Home Page"),
         bottom: TabBar( isScrollable: true,
              tabs: new List.generate(snapshot.data.documents.length, (index) {
                     return new Tab(child: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['name'].toString().toUpperCase()));
              }),)),
```

Then I want from the fire store to get a stream builder of collection named "temps" which has documents inside of it, every document id represents a document id in another collection named "users". In every document in users, i have a field named place. I already made the tabs and it works but,What I can't do is:
wanna get the document id of every document in collection temps, and get this document id and use it to access the documents which has the same id in "users" collection and check if the field place has the same value of the name in the tab bar i wanna appear it in the tab bar view!
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, one solution would be creating a `StatefulWidget`, inside its `State`, using a local `StreamController` and pointing your `StreamBuilder` to it.

Separately, consume both Streams and add these items to your StreamController.

It would look a bit like that:

```
class YourClass extends StatefulWidget {
  ... createState() ...
}


class _YourClassState extends State<YourClass> {
  StreamController<YourItem> _places;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // the unified stream
    _places = new StreamController();

    // listening to changes of the first reference
    CollectionReference places1Ref = Firestore.instance.collection("places1");
    places1Ref.listen((snapshopt) {
      // posting item to the unified streamController
      _places.add(item);
    });

    // listening to changes of the second reference
    CollectionReference places2Ref = Firestore.instance.collection("places2");
    places2Ref.listen((snapshopt) {
      // posting item to the unified streamController
      _places.add(item);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<YourItem>(
      stream: _places.stream, // using here only the unified stream
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return YourWidgets();
      }
    );
  }
}
```

This mockup is using `YourItem` as unified object, but you can use something else, including `dynamic` itself.